# How to get status of airflow DAGs without Airflow UI

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

Airflow UI comes very handy to check the status of Airflow DAG progress.

Airflow Rest API is another way to check the status to Airflow DAGs but it requires authentication token.

We can get authentication token from Airflow UI, but if Airflow UI is down it would be difficult to get authentication token and Airflow DAG status.

Is there any other way to check/monitor and clear task instance from backend (apart from Rest API and Airflow UI) ?

Comment: Why would it be difficult to authenticate? You can do all of that even when webserver is down. The Rest API is not related to the webserver.

Comment: Because its LDAP authentication not the Airflow UI created Users.

Comment: Are you trying to create a monitoring solution or your use case is a specific user would like to know the status of a specific DAG just for the cases where webserver is down?

Comment: Just to ease monitoring DAGs status, when webserver is down

Comment: this is not exactly what you are looking for but why dont you set email notification for both fail and success status? would this be an indirect solution to what you are looking for?

Comment: No, it wont serve the purpose.
By DAG status, i would like to know individual task status, this will help if a task sensor is waiting for something.
Email notification will only let failure/success status of entire DAG.

Answer (score 1):

We have setup status checks on airflow health check endpoint based on this Airflow doc page [Checking Airflow Health Status](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/logging-monitoring/check-health.html). We have serverless functions running every 5 minutes to check that the status for `metabase` and `scheduler` are **healthy**.

When Airflow is down, you can get alerts routed directly to Slack channel / Email / Opsgenie Alerts through another code block defined in the serverless function.

Answer (score 0):

```
from airflow.models.dagrun import DagRun
from airflow.utils.state import DagRunState

dag_runs = DagRun.find(dag_id='the_dag_id_you_want_to_check')
last_run = dag_runs[-1]
print('the dag state is -->: ', last_run.state)
```